# How to execute into a dotnet core docker container

Tags: .net, docker

I have a `Dockerfile` that uses `dotnet` as the base image. I want to **execute** in to the container to test something.

So I tried:

```
docker exec -it eb750806e3e1 powershell
```

But I am getting this error:

> OCI runtime exec failed: exec failed: container_linux.go:345: starting container process caused "exec: "powershell": executable file not found in $PATH": unknown

can someone help me on this please?

Answer (score 5):

It looks like you are on a linux container based on the error message. `Powershell` is not avaliable as the message shows.

Try `docker exec -it eb750806e3e1 bash`.

Comment: If that does not work, try `docker exec -it eb750806e3e1 sh`